# About programming server actions in Odoo/OpenERP

Tags: openerp-7, odoo

I am developing server actions in Odoo 7 of the "Python code" type. How can I know the list of disponible methods that I can call? Where is this documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Server actions are evaluated through the `safe_eval` method in `openerp/tools/safe_eval.py`. The `__builtins__` dict contains the allowed methods. Two things should be noted:

1. `__import__` is not your regular `import`; it is a redefinition that allows you to import `_strptime` and `time` only.
2. `globals` is redefined to return `locals` instead, to keep things neatly sandboxed.

The list of allowed methods, types, etc... is as follows:

- `__import__`
- `True`
- `False`
- `None`
- `str`
- `unicode`
- `globals`
- `locals`
- `bool`
- `int`
- `float`
- `long`
- `enumerate`
- `dict`
- `list`
- `tuple`
- `map`
- `abs`
- `min`
- `max`
- `sum`
- `reduce`
- `filter`
- `round`
- `len`
- `repr`
- `set`
- `all`
- `any`
- `ord`
- `chr`
- `cmp`
- `divmod`
- `isinstance`
- `range`
- `xrange`
- `zip`
- `Exception`

As far as I know, this is not documented anywhere.

Apart from these, you also have access to the following, as noted in the comments on the empty Python Code when you create a server action:

- `self`: ORM model of the record on which the action is triggered
- `object`: Record on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise `None`
- `pool`: ORM model pool (i.e. `self.pool`)
- `cr`: database cursor
- `uid`: current user id
- `context`: current context
- `time`: Python `time` module
- `workflow`: Workflow engine

And the undocumented (you need to check the source of `openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py`):

- `datetime`: Python `datetime` module
- `dateutil`: Python `dateutil` module
- `user`: browse record of current user (contrast with `uid`, which is just his user id)
- `Warning`: `openerp.exceptions.Warning`